# Salesforce1 memory leak with custom vfpage

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, salesforce1-app, debug

We create a lightning ready VF page. 
It works perfectly in Lightning experience on desktop.
But it's really slow in salesforce1 on IOS, and look like creating memory leaks we cannot reproduce on desktop.

When we launch the custom page, close it and relaunch several time, salesforce one crash (after 2 or 3 repetitions maximum)

My feeling is that the iframe created to show the VF page is not destroyed. 
Is their a fix for that ? 
How can we debug apps on salesforce1 ?

Comment: What do you mean by lighting ready VF?

Comment: A Visual Force page with lightning template, working in Lightning experience and salesforce1